# Why is returnPressed called before editingFinished? Can I reorder it?

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I use the `editingFinished` signal to validate/correct/cache some value. When a button is pressed, I then expect the value in the field to be correct.

Now to make my work faster, I connect `returnPressed` to call what the button press would have called. The behavior I expect is this:

- `editingFinished` is emitted, so the application knows the field is edited
- `returnPressed` is emitted, to fire off the "form"'s action

However, I see that the slot connected to `returnPressed` is actually processed first.

Now, I know that I can connect `returnPressed` to another slot that calls the `editingFinished` slot first, and then performs the action, to work around this, but my question is, why is the behavior like this? Or is that the order is unspecified and it just happens to be in this order for me? In the former case, can I change the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is the behavior like this?

Answering this would be conjecture, but it meets my expectations. `editingFinished` sounds like the final call.

> Or is that the order is unspecified and it just happens to be in this order for me?

It appears to not be [explicitly specified](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qlineedit.html#details), but the fact that the description for `editingFinished` comes after `returnPressed` could be taken as a hint.

> In the former case, can I change the order?

Not without changing the source code and recompiling. Just switch the connections.

Answer (score 0):

The order comes from the order in which the signals are emitted in. A directly connected slot works just like a normal function call. Digging through the Qt source code I was able to find this:

[Here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit_p.cpp.html#185) we can see, that `QWidgetLineControl` is in charge of the `returnPressed` and `editingFinished` signals:

```
QObject::connect(control, SIGNAL(accepted()),
    q, SIGNAL(returnPressed()));
QObject::connect(control, SIGNAL(editingFinished()),
    q, SIGNAL(editingFinished()));
```

And as seen [here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qwidgetlinecontrol.cpp.html#1627), `accepted` is emitted before `editingFinished`.

```
emit accepted();
emit editingFinished();
```